# Any nicer way of iterating a number of times specified by an integer value?

Tags: iterator, dart

I have some code like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // do something
}
```

This is just a lot of boilerplate that I don't want to write. Is there anything like [times](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-times) in Ruby:

```
5.times do |i|
  // something
end
```

Which in Dart might look something like:

```
5.times(doSomething);
```

or

```
5.times((i) => doSomething);
```

?

Comment: Just curious, what is the problem you're trying to solve? I can barely imagine the case when one needs to do something constant number of times.

Comment: It's a variable number of times but I wanted the example code to be as simple as I could make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Dart does not (yet?) have similar constructs. We discussed `for (var i in 1.to(5)) doSomething;`, but so far it hasn't been added.

Comment: A `Range` class would be a viable alternative too. I'm sure it was also already suggested.